# Open source "doodle-mailing-list-attendance-coordination" software

Tags: open-source, web-apps, calendar, self-hosted, mailing-list

I am looking for an open source sofware that combines features from Doodle (coordinate appointment attendance) with mailing list (send emails to a group with polls).

#### Functional requirements

- coordinates the attendance of sports team members to appointments (training sessions, games)
- similar to Doodle, but appointments announcements shall be sent to all members via email and team members shall have yes/no/maybe links to respond without opening the web page
- additionally, team members shall be able to open a web page (protected by a generic password that is the same for the entire team), see current polls, add a response or a comment
- optional: a response to the email shall allow team member to comment on their response

#### Non-functional requirements

- open source
- self-hosted: runs on Apache web server, preferably PHP and MySQL based
- web page works for smartphone (responsive design)
- available in English or German

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/), a modern CMS, and written in PHP. It can be used to build a website that will satisfy most, if not all, of your requirements.

These days there are typically 2 releases of it being used:

- Drupal 7, very mature, and zillions of contributed modules (plugins to add specific facilities to a site), release around 2011.
- Drupal 8, pretty new, first beta release dates from late 2014. Major new facilities includes in its core version, but still missing lots of contributed modules (which haven't been upgraded from Drupal 7 yet).

Some more recommendations about specific contributed modules that should help for your case (incomplete list):

- The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, to implement your various groups.
- The [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module; to allow and track user registrations for events, or just about anything you want people to sign up for.